# Como saber o diretório que esta um arquivo.bat quando executado como administrador

Tags: cmd, bat

Estou modificando um otimizador de computador e ele tem comandos do registro que requer execução como administrador.

Ele tem uma pasta que fica no mesmo diretório dele com o nome de `arc`, e onde fica alguns arquivos para o usuário.

Dentro do .bat. ele copia o arquivo e manda para a área de trabalho do usuário.

```
// para copiar utilizei o copy

cd arc                               // vou para a pasta arc
cd 2                                 // vou para a pasta com os arquivos da opção 2 
                                     // (referente ao input do usuário)

@copy x64f.rpf %userprofile%\desktop // copio o arquivo referente a 
                                     // opção para a área de trabalho

cd.. && cd..                         // volto para o diretório atual
```

Nesse caso seria para funcionar, realmente funciona mas, quando rodo como administrador o diretório vai para `C:\Windows\System32`.

Como não sei onde o usuário irá executar, não tem como por um diretório fixo.

Queria saber se tem como saber o diretório em que o arquivo .bat está sendo executado, mesmo com o cmd.exe estando na pasta `C:\Windows\System32`.

Já tentei usar `%cd%` mas ele retorna o valor de `C:\Windows\System32` também.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: `echo %~dp0` veja [Parâmetros do Arquivo de Lote](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/call#batch-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Quando você executa um bat como administrador ou não, o sistema operacional vai chamar a execução o interpretador de comandos `cmd.exe`, e este fica na pasta `C:\Windows\System32`, já passando como argumento (`%0`) o seu arquivo bat.

Quando a chamada é para executar como administrador, a pasta onde está o `cmd.exe` será assumida como pasta de trabalho, e a variavel `%CD%` (que é atualizada dinamicamente em cada uso/execução) vai lhe retornar exatamente isso, o caminho completo (`Drive:` + `\Pasta` + `\SubPasta`) onde está o `\cmd.exe`.

Você pode mudar seu diretório/pasta de trabalho informado/passando o comando `cd` para assumir o `D`rive+`P`asta onde foi o bat foi chamado, utilizando a expanão desses valores direto no argumento `%~dp0`:

```
cd /d "%~dp0arc" // seu bat esta no drive d: e na pasta \Tools 
                 // ​é o mesmo comando: cd /d "d:\Tools\arc"
```

Para verificar se seu bat esta sendo executado como administrador:

```
net file >nul 2>nul 

if %errorlevel% equ 0 (
     echo\Executando como Admin
   )else Executando como Nao Admin
```

Ou, considerando que seu bat não será armazenado e/ou executado direto na mesma pasta do `cmd.exe`:

```
if /i "%cd%\" == "C:\Windows\System32\" (
     echo\Executando como Admin
   )else Executando como Nao Admin
```